# Show / Hide div depending on the img that is clicked Without hard coding the ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CMS that will be updating adding staff members to a site. I have set it up to display a blurb about each member under there corresponding image. I have hidden all of the blurbs onload and only want them displayed once clicked.

Is it possible to remove the unique ID's as the staff members will be add through the CMS and will be changing all of the time.

i also only want to show one blurb at at time, there when one is clicked it will close the other person and only show the correct one.

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/S5G8f/

CSS:

```
.people{
width:500px;
}
.person{
width:33%;
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
}
.people p{
display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="people">

    <div class="person" id="john">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>John doe</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person" id="peter">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Peter Pan</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person" id="sally">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Sally Hills</h2>
    </div>

    <p class="john">John Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p class="peter">Peter Pan is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p class="sally">Sally Hills is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <div class="person" id="betty">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
            <h2>Betty Boo</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person" id="sam">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Sm Hunt</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="person" id="paula">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Paula Walls</h2>
    </div>

    <p class="betty">Betty Jones Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p class="sam">Sam Hunt is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

    <p class="paula">Paula Walls is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$( "#john img" ).click(function() {
  $( "p.john" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
});
$( "#peter img" ).click(function() {
  $( "p.peter" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
});
$( "#sally img" ).click(function() {
  $( "p.sally" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
});
$( "#betty img" ).click(function() {
  $( "p.betty" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
});
$( "#sam img" ).click(function() {
  $( "p.sam" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
});
$( "#paula img" ).click(function() {
  $( "p.paula" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" );
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle link is wrong.

Comment: Fixed, try this http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/S5G8f/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below

```
$("div.person img").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id'); //get the id of the parent div
    //var id = $(this).parent().attr('id'); //This can also be used instead of above.    
    $(".person ~ p:visible").hide(); // hides visible p tags before showing the required one.
    $("p." + id).fadeToggle("fast", "linear"); //show the p tag with the required class
});
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/AMs8k/)

**Note:** As pointed out by Jrn in comments, the `$("p").hide()` will hide all `p` tags in the page because the selector is very generic. Instead ot that we can use a more specific selector to hide only the necessary `p` tags (like say `$(".person ~ p").hide();`). This would hide only `p` tags that is preceded by an element with `class='person'` and has the same parent.

Comment: This will hide every `<p>` tag on the page, and I guess there will be more then in his fiddle. You should work with an `.active` class instead. And do something like `$('p.active').hide();` before you toggle the correct one.

Comment: @Jrn: Completely agreed mate. I should have pointed that out in the sample. I was just trying to show that it can be done.

Comment: I understand your code is more of a "concept", then actual "production" code, I just pointed it out for the people that don't know. :)

Comment: @Jrn: Again, absolutely agreed mate. I have updated the answer to a more specific version :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this without IDs and classes**, but it requires the order of `div.person` and `.people p` to be consistent; ie. if John's picture is the first one in `div.person img` collection, then his description must be the first in `.people p` collection.

See **updated** fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/sPLDh/3/

**jQuery:**

```
$('.person img').click(function() {
    var index = $('.person img').index(this);
    $('.people p:visible')
        .fadeOut('fast','linear')
        .promise()
        .done(function() {
            $('.people p:eq('+index+')')
                .fadeIn('fast','linear');
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="people">

<div class="person">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>John doe</h2>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <h2>Peter Pan</h2>
</div>
<div class="person">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <h2>Sally Hills</h2>
</div>

<p>John Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

<p>Peter Pan is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

<p>Sally Hills is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

<div class="person">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <h2>Betty Boo</h2>
</div>
<div class="person">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <h2>Sm Hunt</h2>
</div>
<div class="person">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    <h2>Paula Walls</h2>
</div>

<p>Betty Jones Doe is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

<p>Sam Hunt is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

<p>Paula Walls is Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sollicitudin molestie ipsum ut fermentum. Duis adipiscing purus gravida, elementum neque nec, mollis tortor.</p>

</div>
```

Also, this won't work if a description of any person consists of more than one `p` tags (if so, you need to use some kind of wrapper, and then `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` those wrappers instead of `p` elements.

Comment: +1. Nice option mate :) By the way, don't forget to add the code to your answer here.

Comment: I improved my fiddle, now it waits for the fadeOut to finish first. Thanksy @Harry, I'm adding it right away ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(".person").on("click", function(e) { 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("people.p").hide();
    $("." + id).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
});
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5G8f/1/)

**EDIT** - Sorry didn't read that you want only one at a time (fixed).

Comment: Close, is it possible to do without the classes and ID's? Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/S5G8f/5/

Comment: @Steve I'm afraid not (not in your case with this html structure).

Comment: @Steve: I think you would still need the ids because each div has a different content.